# PhoneGap + Socialize

Tags: cordova

Has anyone integrated Socialize (getsocialize.com) with PhoneGap? I'm working on a PhoneGap app, and so all of the UI is HTML5, but my client wants us to drop Socialize into the app (love those last minute design changes).

They seem to only have native SDK's, and I guess we could build out a Socialize plugin for PhoneGap but seems like a heavy solution, and I'd rather keep the UI in the HTML5 land to keep everything consistent. I'm not sure what the best path forward is?

Comment: Looks like the answer is no, they have an raw API but no HTML5 drop-in UI. Shame, great concept otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is no. At least not right now.

The only way forward is to either write a phonegap plugin, use their raw API or just build myself.

Answer (score 1):

we're super focused on native iOS & Android right now, and we've built out open-source SDKs for both.

We do have an API you could build against directly for HTML5/PhoneGap.  Here are details: http://api.getsocialize.com/docs/v1/

And if you *wanted* to create some HTML views to approximate the ActionBar, we'd likely be able to put them up at http://www.getsocialize.com/sdk as community-extended SDKs.

Related: You can also get more details about contributing to source here: http://blog.getsocialize.com/source